# Engagement during iddat of a girl

Tags: hadith, nikah, iddah

If any girl is in "iddat"(iddah) and parents wants to see any person for her new marriage. Is it "Halal" to commit any girl with someone during "iddat", although marriage will be done after completion of iddat. Kindly guide me.
Thanks.

Comment: What do you exactly mean by committing any girl with someone? I don't see any harm in proposing for marriage to a woman in 'iddah as the qur'an say's there no harm in it [2:235](https://legacy.quran.com/2/235) the point might be the how to!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

During Iddat women not allowed to even talk with some "Na Mehram", Even she is not allowed to see "Na Mehram".Then how can a women can be committed to someone or get engaged with someone.So this is not allowed during the time period of Iddat ,yes it is allowed after Iddat duration.

Comment: Could you provide any evidences supporting your claims? The qur'an addresses proposals for ladies in their 'iddah in verse 2:235

Answer (score 0):

No its not right because in iddat the lady have to be restricted she is not allowed to met talk and seen by any na mehram so how can be committed to anyone else? 
So the lady have to complete her duration according to Islamic laws then she can committed to any one where she or her parents wants.

Comment: Do you have any evidence for this? See [answer].